# How can i compare an input integer value with the rows of a dataframe and return if they match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I used a for loop and compared it with the variable input, i got neither an output nor an error. can someone help

[Please check the data frame here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvzfT.png)

```
l = []
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if df['rgb'].iloc[i] == df['rgb'].iloc[j]:
            print(df['rgb'].iloc[i])
            l.append(str(df['id'].iloc[i]) +'=='+ str(df['id'].iloc[j]))
l
```

```
z= input() # class str
a =[]
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if df['rgb'].iloc[i] == z:
            print(type(df['rgb'].iloc[i]))   #class str
            a.append(str(df['id'].iloc[i] +'=='+ z))
```

[Please check the executed code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDKOV.png)

I dont get any output here but why? can I not compare variable with dataframe row? then how can I compare the userinput without storing it in a variable. Can someone please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're code is freezing waiting on input() as written.

So you want to return any row where the value you supply is in the column RGB?

If so, does this do what you want?

`df_temp = df[df['rgb'] == '255 255 217 228']`

If not, can you describe a bit better what you are trying to filter for (what "z" is in your eg).